# Ruby check uniqueness

Tags: ruby

I build some code for going through a textfile (webserver logfile). My code works fine, but i have two questions. The code works fine, only the first username visible in the logfile is not printed and not counted. Does anyone know why?

My second question is about my count_unique. What do I need to do to count only the unique usernames?

My Code:

```
count_tot = 0 
count_unique = 0


file = File.new("text.txt", "r")
line = file.gets


while (line = file.gets)


substrings = line.split("&")

substrings.each do |sub|
  if sub.include? 'username'
    puts sub
    count_tot += 1 
  else
  end
end
end

file.close

puts ""
puts "Total found input values:"
puts count_tot
puts count_unique
```

Example input (2 lines)

[11/Mar/2014:00:15:02 +0100] "GET /web/show/id=568296 HTTP/1.1" 200 8499 "https://www.site.com/csc/default.aspx?sid=ertett4353452445.orker2&username=username1&timestamp=20140311001443&hashkey=847823786547385243678&" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.74.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.2 Safari/537.74.9" 52345 1FD323C0D681D2F10AE789F8A6C0900D.wm9worker5
[11/Mar/2014:00:35:50 +0100] "GET /web/show/id=568296 HTTP/1.1" 200 8499 "https://www.site.com/csc/default.aspx?sid=gfdgdfdgfgdfdfg._worker1&username=username2&timestamp=20140311003517&hashkey=fdsfsdffsffds&" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/33.0.1750.14 Mobile/11B651 Safari/9537.53" 62415 5852920B165D2E39559241BA8B5FB36A.wm9worker6

Comment: *What do I need to do to count only the unique usernames?* - Not clear to me.. I need to see the data.. Give the file contents, till 2 lines..

Comment: Ohh!! God.. what you were trying using `line.split("&")` ?

Comment: Hi Arup, I never told i was a good programmer :) But i like to learn. You like to know what i am trying to achieve. So any remarks and improvements are welcome. If there is a smarter method (which i am sure there is) to search through the logfile for all the usernames and count the total and unique usernames, well I would be grateful.

Comment: While you're going through the text file, add those items tagged 'username' into an array.  then you can use `users.count` for the total, and `users.uniq.count` for the unique count

Comment: @tigeravatar. Thats sounds logical, i didnt know about the uniq.count. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: I added the array, works perfect! And even better, on the same array i can do a normal count and a unique count. That removes some other lines of code. So thanks for your help.

Comment: @Derooie see my update.. and let me know if any confusion you are having..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only the first username visible in the logfile is not printed and not counted. Does anyone know why?

For that you need to do

```
line = file.gets # remove this.
while (line = file.gets) # keep only this.
```

`line = file.gets` ( which is before `while` loop), is not being processed. Before entering into the while loop that line data got lost.

**update**

```
string = <<_
[11/Mar/2014:00:15:02 +0100] "GET /web/show/id=568296 HTTP/1.1" 200 8499 "https://www.site.com/csc/default.aspx?sid=ertett4353452445.orker2&username=username1&timestamp=20140311001443&hashkey=847823786547385243678&" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.74.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.2 Safari/537.74.9" 52345 1FD323C0D681D2F10AE789F8A6C0900D.wm9worker5
[11/Mar/2014:00:35:50 +0100] "GET /web/show/id=568296 HTTP/1.1" 200 8499 "https://www.site.com/csc/default.aspx?sid=gfdgdfdgfgdfdfg._worker1&username=username2&timestamp=20140311003517&hashkey=fdsfsdffsffds&" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/33.0.1750.14 Mobile/11B651 Safari/9537.53" 62415 5852920B165D2E39559241BA8B5FB36A.wm9worker6
[11/Mar/2014:00:35:50 +0100] "GET /web/show/id=568296 HTTP/1.1" 200 8499 "https://www.site.com/csc/default.aspx?sid=gfdgdfdgfgdfdfg._worker1&username=username2&timestamp=20140311003517&hashkey=fdsfsdffsffds&" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/33.0.1750.14 Mobile/11B651 Safari/9537.53" 62415 5852920B165D2E39559241BA8B5FB36A.wm9worker6
_

File.write('f1',string)

@usernames = []
File.foreach('f1') do |line|
  #collect all the usernames
  @usernames << line[/username=(\w+)/,1]
  # do other tasks with *line*
end

@usernames # => ["username1", "username2", "username2"]
# to get the uniq usernames
@usernames.uniq # => ["username1", "username2"]
# if you want to see, which username present how many times, think something
# like below
Hash[@usernames.group_by { |s| s }.map { |k,v| [k,v.size]}]
# => {"username1"=>1, "username2"=>2}
```

Look at the method [`IO::foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) to understand why I used it. Checkout the [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) and [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) methods also. Documentation of these are much clear.

Comment: well that was very logical. thank you. i was looking over it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the [`IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html) class, and by extension [`File`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html), has an [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-each) method which yields lines to the block. There is also a [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach) class method that makes it even more concise.

```
File.foreach 'text.txt' do |line|
  # Count stuff ...
end
```

Regarding your first question, that happens because you read the first line into a variable and then proceed to overwrite said variable immediately after in the while loop's clause. This effectively skips the first line. The example above gets rid of that problem.

It is hard to answer the second question without looking at the input we're dealing with.

---

A simple [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-scan)-based solution might suffice:

```
line.scan /[?&]username=([^&]*)/ do |user_name|
  puts user_name
end
```

Everything can thus be simplified to:

```
user_names = File.foreach('text.txt').map do |line|
  line.scan /[?&]username=([^&]*)/
end.flatten

user_name_counts = user_names.uniq.inject Hash.new do |hash, user_name|
  hash.tap do |hash|
    hash[user_name] = user_names.count user_name
  end
end

p user_name_counts
# => {"username1"=>1, "username2"=>2}
```